# camel mail catch Invalid credentials

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I need help in solving the problem of catching an exception like  AuthenticationFailedException.

Generally I want to catching any exception thrown by a camel mail component and then handle exception in some way e.g show the cause of exception to user.

I would like to use ConsumerTemplate to validate camel endpoint :

String imap = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993?username=programmer***@gmail.com&password=****&unseen=false&delete=true&consumer.delay=5000";

Exchange ex = consumerTemplate.receiveNoWait (imap);

Is it possible to find the cause of failure using consumerTemplate?

thanks for any help

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? I'm facing the exact same situation: I want to catch the same AuthenticationFailedException exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if there is any exception thrown, then you can get that from the exchange, using

```
exchange.getException()
```

Comment: Ok , agree with you . But my junit test tell something different : If I use : Exchange exchange = consumerTemplate.receive(imap, 6000); or receiveNoWait unit test give me exchange = null. When I  use right endpoint or endpoint with wrong password , then on console I  can see the real problem in this case - Invalid credentials (Failure) . Any ideas ?